# associate a string with a class so that I can retrieve the string if class is given as generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, metadata

For different classes I need to attach a string to the class (i.e. `Class1` has the string `hello`, `Class2` has the string `world` etc.). Then I will have a generic type parameter `T` somewhere that will be (at runtime) one of these classes. I need to be able to retrieve the associated string from that generic type parameter.

**How do I set this up and make it work?**

Since all classes are written by me, I can use every possible approach (e.g. define common interface for them or common base class or whatever).

I tried creating a base class that has a public static field containing the string, and for each actual class "overwrite" (hide base and create new) the string. But it turned that I still could not retrieve the string when only having the type parameter `T`.

```
public class BaseClass 
{ 
    public static string Get => ""; 
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass 
{ 
    public static new string Get => "hello"; 
} 

public class Class2 : BaseClass 
{ 
    public static new string Get => "world"; 
}

public class Testing<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        string s = T.Get;
        // compiler error: "'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context"
        // strangely though, BaseClass.Get and Class1.Get and Class2.Get work fine!
    }
}
```

---

Real-world use case:

I have a static class `MySerializer<T>` that is supposed to deserialize objects of type `T`. During deserialization I want to validate if my object of type `T` conforms to the schema associated with type `T`.

In order to validate I need to add a schema first. For each class `T` that can be deserialized there is a different schema which I store in my project as an embedded resource, so each schema has a path (like a file path). That means: for each class `T` I need to associate a string (the path) with the class so that I am able to get that path out of `T`.

Here is the relevant part of my serializer and the schema adding process:

```
public static class MySerializer<T>
{
    private static readonly XmlSerializer _mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    private static readonly XmlReaderSettings _settings = new Func<XmlReaderSettings>(() =>
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assy = typeof(MySerializer<T>).Assembly;
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(null,
            XmlReader.Create(assy.GetManifestResourceStream(T.GetAssociatedString())));
            // T.GetAssociatedString(): How to make this work?
        return new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            Schemas = schemas,
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
                XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints
        };
    })();

    public static T Deserialize(Stream strm)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strm, _settings))
        {
            return (T)_mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Then I will have a generic type parameter T somewhere that will be (at runtime) one of these classes." Generics exist only at compile time. At runtime they are as set in stone as any other type. Still allowing Compile time checks is **exactly** what they are there for. If you want to get around compile time checks, boxing/casting to object and dynamic are the only ways. But not ways you should carelessly take. Strong Typisation is your friend, do not fight it.

Comment: `BaseClass.Get` works because it's static while others are not.

Comment: @Christopher Since (in my not working try of solving it) I defined `T` as inheriting from `BaseClass`, I cannot see why `T.Get` does not work. It should be clear at compile time that it works. I do not want to get around compile time checks at all, I just want some way of utilizing the information that I give to `T`. But the compiler does not let me, no idea why.

Comment: Are you able to determine the paths yourself? you could use something like `typeof(T).Name` to get the class name and then integrate that in the pathing like `$"MyClasses/{typeof(T).Name}/somethingsomething"`

Comment: @icebat All three example classes have a static `Get` property. And since `T` inherits from `BaseClass`, it has the static `Get` property as well (as far as I understand inheritance).

Comment: There are better ways to do what you are trying to do. Easy way is to use a switch on the type (because according to OOP the type shouldn't know a damn thing about its given name in the serializer) , another way is to use `Attribute` on each class

Comment: I recommend the attribute, although I wouldn't put a path in it. That couples the code to that particular implementation detail. I'd just put something that identifies the schema, and then use some other lookup to retrieve the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since static methods and generic type parameters don't work together in C# (thanks to Matthew Watson for linking to Eric Lippet's Blog) and I don't want to create a new instance of `T` solely to be able to call a method, I'll go with attributes.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class SomeStringAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public SomeStringAttribute(string s)
    {
        SomeString = s;
    }
}

[SomeString("hello")]
public class Class1
{ 
} 

[SomeString("world")]
public class Class2
{ 
}

public class Testing<T>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        string s =
            ((SomeStringAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeStringAttribute),
                false)[0]).SomeString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use reflection to do this, but note that all the properties need to be static (your sample code above introduces non-static properties to the derived class).

Here's a compilable example:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public static string Get => "";
    }

    public class Class1 : BaseClass
    {
        public new static string Get => "hello";
    }

    public class Class2 : BaseClass
    {
        public new static string Get => "world";
    }

    public class Testing<T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty("Get");

            if (property != null)
                return (string) property.GetValue(null, null);

            return null;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test1 = new Testing<Class1>();
            Console.WriteLine(test1.Test());  // Prints "hello"

            var test2 = new Testing<Class2>();
            Console.WriteLine(test2.Test()); // Prints "world"
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the `where T : BaseClass` isn't actually needed for it to compile and work, but you might want to keep it to make it clear that it is only supposed to be used with classes that inherit from `BaseClass`.

Comment: corrected my question: the getters of the derived classes were meant to be static, i forgot the static keyword but now added it

Comment: Sure, but it's cannon balls on sparrows. I still hope there is a way without utilizing reflection. I mean, nobody could explain to me yet why `T.Get` gives a compile error although `T` clearly has everything that `BaseClass` has.

Comment: @Kjara Look at [Eric Lippert's blog here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/14/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-one/).